# Primefaces ajax not working

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a strange issue. I am developing an application on Jboss 7 using JSF, SEAM and Primefaces. Recently I had a strange problem. In my template I have two controls: 
1. Categories
2. Channels

When a user clicks on a desired category, the block with channels is updated. If the user clicks on channel he goes to mysite.www/channel/idofchannel. On the first page everything works allright. But when the user is transfered to mysite.www/channel/idofchannel, the controls do not work. When I click on the category, the action of commandLink is executed, but does not update the block with channels. Does it have to do anything with f:viewParam?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without your source code, I can only guess. If you are using `p:commandLink` then the reason might be, that it submits an ajax request by default. Then you have to use the `update` attribute to specify the components that will be updated by this ajax call.

Here is an example from the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandLink.jsf):

```
<p:commandLink id="ajax" update="panel,display" 
            actionListener="#{pprBean.savePerson}">  
    <h:outputText value="Ajax Submit" />  
</p:commandLink>
```

Another option would be to set `ajax=false` and submit a full request:

```
<p:commandLink id="nonAjax" actionListener="#{pprBean.savePerson}" style="margin-right:20px;" ajax="false">  
    <h:outputText value="Non-Ajax Submit" />  
</p:commandLink>
```